# How to use FetchXml for Mobile Reports of Resco Mobile CRM App?

Tags: mobile, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a SSRS Report in CRM. I want to use this report in my Resco mobile app. The data shown in the report comes from two different entities having no proper relationships , but the join between these two entities is based on a Text Field (String). I have the fetchXML which brings the data. How to use this fetch xml in woodford to show the data in Mobile App (offline/online) mood.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the documentation:
[MobileCRM.MobileReport.runReport Function](http://www.resco.net/mobilecrm/support/jsbridge.aspx#MobileCRM.MobileReport)